# MYSQL Left join and select all creating null values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables roughly designed like this

```
id | title | price
```

&

```
id | title | price | description
```

I am trying to use a LEFT JOIN to match the results by "id".

This works if I state exactly which table the title should come from i.e a.title. But what I need to do is list the title and price from the second table if it has results. If there are no result from the second table then the first tables results for title a price should be used. When I do any combination of results using select all for both tables it just gives NULL values for the columns that are present in both tables, i.e all but description.

Comment: Are those table linked by a foreign key?Show your query(s)

Comment: It's just a normal text book JOIN LEFT query, very basic with nothing extra.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing some sort of search and fallback feature.  That is not joining.

Comment: In any case I have tried numerous variations which I have tried to surmise in the question.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ it's not really a case of omitting results but rather showing data for result that is returned, instead of null.

Comment: LEFT JOIN with SELECT a.*, b.* will show results when there entries in both tables but for some reason returns null values on columns shared by each table

Comment: It depends what table you are selecting 'FROM' and what table you are 'LEFT JOIN'ing with and what fields you are joining 'ON'. We will try to help you if you are more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try left join with

```
coalesce(secondTable.price,firstTable.price) as price, 
coalesce(secondTable.title,firstTable.title) as title
```